# return statement missing on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

i'm doing an android app. and suddenly this error keeps on appearing, 
what could the error be? please do help me :(
    i'm using and android studio IDE
   though i'm following instructions i could not figure out what seems to be the problem. i'm very new to the environment also.

```
/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String[] forecastArray = {
                "Today - Foggy - 12/3",
                "Tomorrow - Rainy - 7/4",
                "Wed - Sunny - 12/3",
                "Thurs - Cloudy - 10/4",
                "Fri - Rainy - 12/8",
                "Sat - Heavy Rain- 10/5",
                "Sun - Sunny - 32/23"

        };
        List<String> weekforecast = new ArrayList<String>(
                Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

        mForecastAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,

        weekforecast);
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            try {
                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                URL url = new URL("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=7000&mode=json&units=metric&ch+7&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f");

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: You have posted code, but you did not post what error you are receiving.

Comment: sorry. the error appears on the second to the last } it says return statement missing..

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Async class out side, like that:
EDIT : 
add return null after finally.

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

public MainActivityFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

    String[] forecastArray = {
            "Today - Foggy - 12/3",
            "Tomorrow - Rainy - 7/4",
            "Wed - Sunny - 12/3",
            "Thurs - Cloudy - 10/4",
            "Fri - Rainy - 12/8",
            "Sat - Heavy Rain- 10/5",
            "Sun - Sunny - 32/23"

    };
    List<String> weekforecast = new ArrayList<String>(
            Arrays.asList(forecastArray));

    mForecastAdapter =
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    getActivity(),
                    R.layout.list_item_forecast,
                    R.id.list_item_forecast_textview,

                    weekforecast);
    ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_item_forecast);
    listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

    return rootView;
}


public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>


{


    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
        String forecastJsonStr = null;

        try {
            // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
            // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
            // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
            URL url = new URL("api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=7000&mode=json&units=metric&ch+7&appid=bd82977b86bf27fb59a04b61b657fb6f");

            // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Read the input stream into a String
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (inputStream == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                return null;
            }
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                return null;
            }
            forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error ", e);
            // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
            // to parse it.
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("PlaceholderFragment", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }
}
```

}

Comment: it still outputs the same error. i added a return null before the second to the last } and i think its ok. but i don't know why. by the way thanks . @Shahar

Comment: missed that... you should return null after finally{}.

Comment: sorry @shahar my reputation is still low can't make an upvote .:3

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the return type of method `Void doInBackground(Void... params)` is `Void` and not `void`. It is not the primitive `void` but a class representing it, in the same way `Integer` class represents `int`.

It being a class and return type of your method you need to add a return statement at end of all the execution path. In your method if execution path goes to `finally` clause there is no return statement and hence the error.